# How can I describe someone that is "extremely set on a certain value"

Tags: synonyms

Example: Moderators of XYZ discussion board push those less [word here] , to agree with their beliefs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> **entrenched** *adjective*
>   (of an attitude, habit, or belief) firmly established and difficult or unlikely to change; ingrained.
>   ‘an entrenched resistance to change’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/entrenched)

I’d remove the comma from your sample sentence, leaving:

- Moderators of XYZ discussion board push those less **entrenched** to agree with their beliefs.